# Java test report that includes logs

Tags: java, maven, gradle, junit

Is there a maven or gradle plugin that produces html report including the log output for each test case (pass or fail)?

I have tried surefire with maven and it doesn’t seem to provide such capabilities.

I kind of like the html test report you get by exporting on intellij.

Answer (score -1):

In maven you can do it via surefire-report like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

Or in command line: `mvn surefire-report:report`

With gradle, you do it like this:

```
test {
    reports {
        html.enabled = true
    }               
}
```

Reference this for gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:reports

EDIT:
to include logs from sys.out/sys.err do this inside your pom surefire plugin braces:

```
    <configuration>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Surefire doesn’t include the log output in html report.

Comment: Oh, sorry my fault, didnt know you need logs, it does, edited my answer

Comment: Gradle includes the log output in the html reports. And am looking for a similar solution using maven. With surefire, the log gets saved as txt file but they are not part of the html.